# Detect touch within a radius of a node in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a player object in my SpriteKit game and at the moment I'm moving it using the following code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (touches.count == 1)
    {
        [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    if (touches.count == 1)
    {
        [_player runAction:[SKAction moveTo:[[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self] duration:0.01]];
    }
}
```

But I only want to move the player node when the touch is within a specific range of the location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it looks like you only care about the distance of the touch from your `_player` object, I would move the radius detection logic to your `_player` object and use an `SKRegion` to handle it.

**Note:** *If you need to know if your touch is within the radius of multiple nodes then you might want to use a method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251706/ios-spritekit-how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-nodes) instead.*

To use an `SKRegion` to determine if your touch is within a certain radius of `_player`, add an `SKRegion` instance to your `_player` object and initialize it with the radius you want. In `[_player init]` or wherever it makes the most sense for your project:

`self.touchRegion = [[SKRegion alloc] initWithRadius:radius];`

Then add a method to determine if a point is within that region:

```
- (BOOL)pointIsInTouchRegion:(CGPoint)point {
    return [self.touchRegion containsPoint: point];
}
```

Next change your `touchesMoved` method to something like:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    if (touches.count == 1)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint point = [self locationInNode:_player]; // NOTE: It's important to use _player here!
        if ([_player pointIsInTouchRegion: point]) {
            [_player runAction:[SKAction moveTo:[[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self] duration:0.01]];
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** *Using `_player` in `[self locationInNode:_player];` is critical since your `SKRegion` will be defined in the `_player` node's coordinate system.*

One more note: You don't really have to put all that logic in `_player`, that's just the way I would do it. You could just as easily store the `SKRegion` in your scene's class and call `[region containsPoint: point]` on it directly.

---

**Update: iOS 7 method**

The main difference with doing this for iOS 7 is that you need to store the actual radius you're interested in rather than an `SKRegion` (since it's only available in iOS 8), and then do the calculation yourself in `pointIsInTouchRegion:`.

So, in `_player`, set your touch radius where you were setting the `touchRegion` before:

`self.touchRadius = radius`

Then change the `pointIsInTouchRegion:` method so that it does the actual distance calculation.

```
- (BOOL)pointIsInTouchRegion:(CGPoint)point {
    CGPoint centerOfNode = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.frame.size.height / 2.0); // NOTE: If this is in an SKSpriteNode, you might want to use self.anchorPoint instead
    CGFloat distanceToCenter = return hypotf(point.x - centerOfNode.x, point.y - centerOfNode.y);
    return (distanceToCenter <= self.radius);
}
```

The code in `touchesMoved` should not need any changes.

Comment: It says on the Apple Documentation it's only available in iOS 8 and later, does this code not work in iOS 7?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I hadn't realized that was an iOS 8 only class. I can update the answer with a method that'll work for iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

The following demonstrates how to 1) select a sprite that is within a specified distance from a touch event and 2) drag and drop the selected sprite to a new location.

```
@interface MyScene()

@property (weak) SKSpriteNode *selectedNode;

@end

@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        // Add three sprites to scene
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(32, 32)];
        sprite.name = @"Blue";
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                      CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-64);
        [self addChild:sprite];

        sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(32, 32)];
        sprite.name = @"Red";
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                      CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 64);
        [self addChild:sprite];


        sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(32, 32)];
        sprite.name = @"Green";
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                      CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
    return self;
}

#define kRadius     64

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    _selectedNode = nil;
    CGFloat minDistance = kRadius+1;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        for (SKSpriteNode *node in self.children) {
            CGFloat dx = location.x - node.position.x;
            CGFloat dy = location.y - node.position.y;
            // Compute distance from sprite to tap point
            CGFloat distance = sqrtf(dx*dx+dy*dy);
            if (distance <= kRadius) {
                if (distance < minDistance) {
                    // Select the closest node so far
                    _selectedNode = node;
                    minDistance = distance;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    if (_selectedNode) {
        // Move selected node to current touch position
        _selectedNode.position = location;
    }
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Unselect node
    _selectedNode = nil;
}

- (void) update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this, forgive me if I mis understand your question however:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

if (touches.count == 1) && (point.x == yourObjectsXPosition) && (point.y ==  yourObjectsYPosition) 

     {
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you know anyway of adding a radius to this, for example if I touch near the player it will still move

Comment: What I would do is just say if the x is greater than a certain point and less that a certain point then, I'd do the same for y then also. (Use the complete left of the object as the greater than value for x and the complete right as the less than. Top and bottom also for the y value.