# Calculate fall time in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am using SpriteKit and I need to calculate the fall time of an object (since it changes depending on the screen size). The problem is that the gravity of the scene is given in m/s^2, but all distances are measured in points.

I have tried to find the conversion between points and meters, but it was not very successful.

Any suggestions in how to deal with it?

Comment: if the issue is the scene size is different,  why not calculate the difference and apply it to the gravity.  e.g.  iphone 5 is 568pts, iphone 4 is 480pts, so that is 1.183333 times faster going from iphone 4 to iphone 5, so the formula should  be (m/s^2) * 1.18333333

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251706/ios-spritekit-how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-nodes) (A distance calculator written by another on StackOverflow) to calculate the distance between your node and the point directly below it near the ground or another empty node, then plug that distance into an equation to calculate the time.

Unfortunately, I can't give you any code because I've never tried this myself.